# No view found for SettingsFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-view, android-preferences

I have this in my `MainActivity`:

```
settingsImageView.setOnClickListener {
    val settingsFragment = SettingsFragment()
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, settingsFragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

In my `SettingsFragment`, I have the following:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)
    }
}
```

I don't have a `SettingsActivity`, just a fragment. When I run my app and click on the settings button, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0088 (com.comp.main:id/container) for fragment SettingsFragment{3974426} (893fe5bb-55d2-4db9-bf6d-69909cb9711e id=0x7f0a0088)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

How do I fix this? Do I need a `SettingsActivity`?

Comment: Do you have any view with id ```R.id.container```?

Comment: So I realized that and changed it to `R.id.settings_container` which is the id my `fragment_settings.xml` has for its `FrameLayout`. However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you try using ```childFragmentManager``` instead of ```supportFragmentManager```? I am assuming the fragment is nested.

Comment: @Eishon There doesn't seem to be a `childFragmentManager` for Kotlin.